# How to add a validation in a bootstrap form with FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, button, fullcalendar

I am doing a shift system for a barber shop, using FullCalendar.
I added a custombutton (FullCalendar provides it), which opens a new window to complete a form with name, day and hour, but I need to add a validation for the day and the hour.
For example:
Haircut days only are available from Tuesday to Saturday, and on the hours of 10 AM until 7 PM, so I need a validation in the form for that.
So I added this to the FullCalendar code in Javascript:

```js
customButtons: {
    custom1: {
      text: 'Ask haircut shift',
      click: function(){
        // Opens form in a new windows
        var popup = window.open('haircut-shift.html', 'Ask shift', 'width=500,height=500');
        popup.onbeforeunload = function(){
          calendar.refetchEvents();
        };
      }
    }
```

As you can see, `window.open` refeers to another `.html` archive that contains the form (made with bootstrap).
Tried to add another function that checks day and hour but seems not to be working properly, because whenever I select Monday and 9 PM i.e., let's me save it without any alert.
Tried to add another function to test the validation but doesn't worked:

```js
eventClick:function(info){
  if (info.event.start.getDay() < 2 || info.event.start.getDay() > 6) {
    alert("Haircut shift only available from tuesday to saturday");
      return;
  }
  if (info.event.start.getHours() < 10 || info.event.start.getHours() >= 19) {
    alert("Haircut shift only available from 10 AM until 7 PM");
      return;
  }
  var popup = window.open(
    "haircut-shift.html",
    "Ask shift",
    "width=500,height=500"
  );
  popup.onbeforeunload = function () {
      calendar.refetchEvents();
  };
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `I need a validation in the form for that`...so what code did you write to do that? I expect would need to be in the .html file where the form is. `eventClick` has nothing to do with it...that handles a user clicking on an existing event (you can read about this in the fullcalendar documentation).